# Truncating the post date of a Wordpress post with PHP

Tags: php, string, wordpress, date

I'm trying to manipulate the output of Wordpress' the_date() function.

My code:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/gnews/wp-blog-header.php');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

$potatoes = the_date();
$themonth = substr($potatoes,3);
echo($themonth);

endwhile; else: 
endif;  
?>
```

Pardon the strange variable names, at wit's end here.

No matter what I try, the above will only output June 17th 2011.

The end result I'd like is to set it up so that I have a three character month name in one variable, a two-digit date number in another variable, and the year in a third. The date has to be the date of the Wordpress post however.

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: what does var_dump($potatoes); produce?

Comment: It produces `NULL NULL` . Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Then i'm assuming that `$themonth` is also `NULL` and `June 17th 2011` is being output elsewhere.

Comment: It seems to just be echoed. `the_date();` doesn't seem to return anything but instead echo the post date to the page. How can I "harness" that into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish these to be in 3 variables, pass the output of `the_date()` into `strtotime()` and `date('Y-M-d)` and then `explode()` it into separate variables. [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is perfectly capable of parsing a date like `June 17th 2011`.

```
// Get it in YYYY-Mon-dd
$date = date('Y-M-d', strtotime(the_date());
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);
```

#### Update

[Wordpress' `the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date)'s fourth parameter is a boolean which specifies whether to return or echo it. It isn't necessary to use `strtotime()` if done this way:

```
// Call the_date() with its format and FALSE to echo
$date = the_date('Y-M-d', '', '', FALSE);
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);
```

Comment: But the problem is that the_date() doesn't seem to return anything. It seems to just echo the date of the blog post to the screen and leaves you with no variables. I'm basically trying to find a way to harness that _into_ a variable. Do you know how I'd do that?

Comment: Find out where the_date() is declared (im assuming in gnews/wp-blog-header.php), and see how it accesses the date.  Then either modify or override the functionality.

Comment: @Pirate43 See addition above. There's an option for that to `the_date()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! With the above I can do exactly what I need to :D